# multi-threadings and multi-processes pools in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

As for multi-threadings and multi-processes pools in `multiprocessing`

```
 pool = Pool()
 result = pool.map(func, arg)
 pool.close()
 pool.join()
```

Why `close` and `join` are necessary to make the code **safe**? What bad consequences can it make without them?

In a loop, it's better to put these lines inside or outside the loop?

For example,

```
 pool = Pool()
 for x in a_ndarray:
     result = pool.map(func, x)
     save(result)
     pool.close()
     pool.join()
```

and

```
 pool = Pool()
 for x in a_ndarray:
     result = pool.map(func, x)
     save(result)
 pool.close()
 pool.join()
```

I saw others suggested multi-processes for CPU-bound tasks and multi-threadings for IO-bound tasks. But what are the disadvantages of applying multi-threading to CPU-bound and multi-processes to IO-bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lee Hi Folk,

Basically, these instructions will set some closure concepts into the current executions, it will say "I won't put more data into the queue(`close`) and I'll wait the end of the sub-processes before go on(`join`)".

From docs:

> close()
>
> Indicate that no more data will be put on this queue by the current >process. The background thread will quit once it has flushed all buffered data to the pipe. This is called automatically when the queue is garbage collected.

---

> join()
>
> Block until all items in the queue have been gotten and processed.
>
> The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an item is added to the queue. The count goes down whenever a consumer thread calls task_done() to indicate that the item was retrieved and all work on it is complete. When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, join() unblocks.

Source: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

This will make better and safer your code because it will use this information to do a proper *Garbage Collection* and will avoid *weird or unwanted* behavior of the code like ending the main process before child processes end.

For example, if after launch the sub-processes you call a function that could vary in time execution:

```
pool = Pool()
for x in a_ndarray:
    result = pool(func, x)
    save(result)
non_fixed_time_function() #this could take 0.1 s or 2 hours.
#pool.join() # Don't wait for child to finish
```

If you don't wait for child to finish, in a execution could do exactly as you want, in other could finish just one child or 2 children, and this would cause weird results.

About your second question, in that scenario, I would take the `.close()` and `.join()` methods inside the loop, before save the result.

Comment: I got that `close` and `join` are useful for releasing the pool resources. But since `map` itself blocks until the result is ready, why `close` and `join` are necessary? Does `non_fixed_time_function` start some other subprocesses related or not related to `pool`? If not related, `join` can monitor any subprocesses?

Comment: Sorry, where did you use `map`?, regarding the code you posted, it will not block itself unless you explicitly use `join`.

Comment: Sorry it should be `pool.map()`, not `pool()` in the Q.